# WordPress post values into new class object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to put WordPress post values into a new class object so I can return back to my `Ajax post`

**What i've currently got:**

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  GetLatestBlogPost();
});

function GetLatestBlogPost()
{
  $.ajax(
  {
      url: "IsosecWeb/php/getLatestBlogPost.php",
      type: 'POST',
      beforeSend: function()
      {
          console.log("Before send...");
      },
      success: function (successData) 
      {
         console.log(successData);
         console.log("successful send...");
      },
      error: function(errorData)
      {
          // Loading data loader
          console.log("Error send...");
      }
  });
}
```

**PHP (Get WordPress post values)**

```
require('../../blog/wp-blog-header.php'); 

// Create an object to store the data to be returned in
$returnObject = new stdClass();

function GetFirstLastestBlogPost()
{

    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'offset' => 0, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 

    $returnObject->getFirstImage = getTheFirstImage();
    $returnObject->getBlogDate = the_date();
    $returnObject->getTitle = the_title();
    $returnObject->getContent = wp_trim_words(preg_replace("/\< *[img][^\>]*[.]*\>/i","", get_the_content(), 80), 80);
    $returnObject->getAuthorLink = the_author_posts_link();

    endforeach;  

    return $returnObject;
}

function getTheFirstImage() 
{
    $files = get_children('post_parent='.get_the_ID().'&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image');
    if($files) :
        $keys = array_reverse(array_keys($files));
        $j=0; $num = $keys[$j];
        $image=wp_get_attachment_image($num, 'large', false);
        $imagepieces = explode('"', $image);
        $imagepath = $imagepieces[1];
        $thumb=wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($num);
        echo "<img src='$thumb' class='thumbnail' />";
    endif;
}

echo json_encode(GetFirstLastestBlogPost());
```

**Returned console message**

```
Before send...

<img src='http://isosec.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/CJ9WINoWEAARSPW-150x150.jpg' class='thumbnail' />July 22, 2015EHI Awards: Finalists Announced<a href="http://isosec.co.uk/blog/?author=7" title="Posts by Jo Flynn" rel="author">Jo Flynn</a>{"getFirstImage":null,"getBlogDate":null,"getTitle":null,"getContent":"You may have read in our blog some weeks ago that we had been shortlisted for the EHI Awards 2015 in the Excellence in Mobile Healthcare category. At the time we didn\u2019t know a lot about who else was involved or the overall process but we have a lot more to share as we are now\u2026 Finalists! As you can imagine we are very excited about this, so in this blog we thought it would share a little more about&hellip;","getAuthorLink":null}

successful send...
```

It's not returning the message with the key values. Does anyone know why this is happening?

**expected outcome**

- KEY: getFirstImage Value: Image
- KEY: getBlogDate   Value: Date
- KEY: getTitle      Value: Title
- KEY: getContent    Value: Content
- KEY: getAuthor     Value: Author

Output given from [Tomasz Struczyński's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31673499/3296661) answer:

```
Before send...
getBlogPost.js:26 Error... 
getBlogPost.js:27 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"July 22, 2015EHI Awards: Finalists Announced<a href=\"http://isosec.co.uk/blog/?author=7\" title=\"Posts by Jo Flynn\" rel=\"author\">Jo Flynn</a>{\"getFirstImage\":\"http:\\/\\/isosec.co.uk\\/blog\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2015\\/07\\/CJ9WINoWEAARSPW-150x150.jpg\",\"getBlogDate\":null,\"getTitle\":null,\"getContent\":\"You may have read in our blog some weeks ago that we had been shortlisted for the EHI Awards 2015 in the Excellence in Mobile Healthcare category. At the time we didn\\u2019t know a lot about who else was involved or the overall process but we have a lot more to share as we are now\\u2026 Finalists! As you can imagine we are very excited about this, so in this blog we thought it would share a little more about&hellip;\",\"getAuthorLink\":null}","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

Comment: First thing, I don't see where in your code you print your object - it is just returned. You should do something like `echo json_encode(GetFirstLastestBlogPost());`. Second thing, the output you get is probably caused by `getTheFirstImage`, so could you share the code of this function?

Comment: @vard Added the `getTheFirstImage` function

Comment: @vard I've also updated it to `echo json_encode(GetFirstLatestBlogPost());` - It's now outputting something different to what it did firstly

Comment: Please, add the exact output from the server (you can get it from debug console in Chrome or Firefox) as a comment or part of the question. Wordpress may be sending additional headers, which collide with json output, for example. That's why I suggest doing it 'wordpress' way, by using proper hooks.

Comment: @TomaszStruczyński I've update my question, to show the exact ouput i'm getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE - added content-type header set**

First of all, **you should consider using standard Wordpress AJAX hooks** as described here: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

As for your approach:

In plain PHP you have to print your return value. Simply returning it from function doesn't cause it to be sent back to client. You have to echo it somehow. I suggest JSON format, as it will be quite easy to program.

> For frontend - add dataType: 'json' to your request like that:

```
$.ajax(
  {
      url: "IsosecWeb/php/getLatestBlogPost.php",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function()
      {
          console.log("Before send...");
      },
     success: function (successData) 
     {
        console.log(successData);
        console.log("successful send...");
     },
     error: function(errorData)
     {
          // Loading data loader
         console.log("Error send...");
     }
  });
```

> And then the backend:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require('../../blog/wp-blog-header.php'); 

// Create an object to store the data to be returned in

function GetFirstLastestBlogPost()
{
    $returnObject = new stdClass();

    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'offset' => 0, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($postslist as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post); 

        $returnObject->getFirstImage = getTheFirstImage();
        $returnObject->getBlogDate = the_date();
        $returnObject->getTitle = the_title();
        $returnObject->getContent = wp_trim_words(preg_replace("/\< *[img][^\>]*[.]*\>/i","", get_the_content(), 80), 80);
        $returnObject->getAuthorLink = the_author_posts_link();
    }

    return $returnObject;
}

function getTheFirstImage() 
{
    $files = get_children('post_parent='.get_the_ID().'&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image');
    if($files) {
        $keys = array_reverse(array_keys($files));
        $j=0; $num = $keys[$j];
        $image=wp_get_attachment_image($num, 'large', false);
        $imagepieces = explode('"', $image);
        $imagepath = $imagepieces[1];
        $thumb=wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($num);
        return $thumb;
    }
    return null;
}

echo json_encode(GetFirstLastestBlogPost());
```

I have changed code styling to standards (PSR-0 and following), as the notation without curled braces is used mainly in teplates, not in functions.

Comment: I've updated my question with an output given from your answer

Comment: The problem come from this `echo "<img src='$thumb' class='thumbnail' />";`. You display the image, this is why you get it in your output. return it instead of echo-ing it and it will be allright. See in Tomasz answer his changes to the `getTheFirstImage` function.

Comment: Exactly. I don't have 'echo' in my answer :)

Comment: @vard Tomasz isn't using `echo "<img src='$thumb' class='thumbnail' />";` in his answer. I'm using `echo <img...>` in my original code. But then I tried Tomasz way and got different output as updated in my question

Comment: @ChrisBeckett Please, see my comment in your question.

Comment: One more update - I have added explicit setting content type header in backend. Please, see if this helps.

Comment: @TomaszStruczyński that worked. However it still returning in error instead of success. Do you know why?

Comment: @TomaszStruczyński Sorry my bad, I was returning null values. So it was causing it to error. You code work. Cheers! :)